# what does `handle SIG33 pass nostop noprint` does when used in gdb

Tags: linux, debian, gdb

In gdb, the usual instructions for debugging given are -

```
gdb $package

set logging on

set pagination 0

handle SIG33 pass nostop noprint

run
```

and of course than collecting backtraces and all. Of the above, what does

```
handle SIG33 pass nostop noprint
```

and where it should be used and where not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
handle SIG33
```

tells `gdb` how to handle signal 33; in the version you give, `pass` means to pass the signal on, `nostop` tells the debugger not to stop when the signal is emitted, and `noprint` not to print anything.

This kind of directive is useful when debugging runtimes which use signals internally. Signal 33 is used on Android, by Bionic (for back-traces); if you don’t ignore it there you’ll end up stopping all the time. You’d see similar instructions with Flash (with signals 32 and 33 at least, IIRC).