# is there a way to know if signals are present in your application and which signals are there?

Tags: signals, gdb

Please see [what does `handle SIG33 pass nostop noprint` does when used in gdb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378866/what-does-handle-sig33-pass-nostop-noprint-does-when-used-in-gdb) . I am guessing from the answer shared by Stephen Kitt, that info. about signals is in the source code somewhere. If I download the source code of a particular app, say leafpad http://tarot.freeshell.org/leafpad/ how can I search for which signals are present. The idea is to do better debugging.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "which signals are present"? You mean which ones has the program been written to deal with? Why would that be relevant?

Comment: Which signals would be a handled is a runtime thing: a program can pretty much arbitrarily install and remove signal handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the signals that a given application handles, on its own, look for `sigaction` and `signal` calls in the source code. Libraries can also set up signal handlers, so you really need to look at those too...

Without looking at the source code, you can look for those using `strace` which has specific support for signal-related syscalls:

```
strace -e trace=signal ...
```

This will run your program and dump details of all signal-related syscalls. From that you will be able to determine which signals are used.

Comment: This only helps for compiled executables though. What if the program is in Perl or Python or any other interpreted language? I don't think this can be answered with a single global answer.

Comment: @terdon you `strace` the interpreter then ;-). But yes, the source code part doesn’t help with anything other than C/C++...