# How to figure out signal numbers using strace in an application?

Tags: debian, signals, debugging

Please have a look at [is there a way to know if signals are present in your application and which signals are there?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379694/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-signals-are-present-in-your-application-and-which-sign) in which Stephen Kitt shared a solution -

```
strace -e trace=signal ...
```

now just to know, have fun, understand I ran the command as -

```
$] strace -e trace=signal qbittorrent
```

as I ran it, I got the output as -

```
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7faabe532bd0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7faabe53e0c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7faabe532c60, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7faabe53e0c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7faabd925030}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7faabd925030}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7faabd925030}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7faabd925030}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7faabd925030}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x5628b7cd2960, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7faabd925030}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x5628b7cd2960, sa_mask=[TERM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7faabd925030}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, {sa_handler=0x5628b7cd2b00, sa_mask=[ABRT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7faabd925030}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {sa_handler=0x5628b7cd2b00, sa_mask=[SEGV], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7faabd925030}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
```

now how do I figure out which/what signal number I should give in order to provide better debugging to the maintainer in case of a crash or something ?

Looking forward to know.

Comment: You're asking what signal to send to (e.g. qbittorrent) in order to create a debug log?

Comment: If you're looking for a mapping from signal names (`SIGABRT`) to signal numbers, you can issue `kill -l` (arg is letter ell, not number one).

Comment: @JeffSchaller , you would better understand my query if you see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378866/what-does-handle-sig33-pass-nostop-noprint-does-when-used-in-gdb but in essence yes, want to be able to give the distribution package maintainer more info.

Comment: @user4556274 I know `ps aux | grep $PACKAGENAME` to get what PID that app. got and then kill it in case the app/package hangs, don't understand what you are saying, could you elaborate ?

Comment: the strace output is showing which signals are being handled, but it's up to each application how they do (or do not) produce debug output.

Comment: @Jeff you should turn your comment into an answer, there’s nothing much to add...

Comment: If the existing answer solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can't, in general.

The strace output shows which signals are being handled, but it's up to each application how they do (or do not) produce debug output. Maybe they do it when receiving a SIGHUP, maybe upon a SIGUSR1, or maybe with a `-D` startup flag, or maybe not at all.